# Csv file not found in a .py ending file

Tags: python, csv, visual-studio-code

so I was trying to open a simple csv file in VS code that I recently downloaded. But the terminal kept saying “gdptable1.csv” not found after running the code. And I clicked “start debugging” as well, but the result is still the same——no such file or directory: ‘gdptable1.csv’

BUT after I created a new file ending with .ipynb, things worked! VS code was able to exhibit the content of the csv file.

I wonder why this is and how I could fix this in the .py ending file. Is there any difference between .py and .ipynb file? Or am I lacking any extensions?

I tried to run the code below in these two files:

```
import csv

with open('gdptable1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for i in rows:
      print(i)
```

Comment: You must understand that when working with relative paths, the path is relative to your current working directory. i.e. the csv file you are looking for must be in your current working directory. At some point in the process of creating the `ipynb` file you changed the CWD to the one where the file is.

Comment: it's best to provide absolute paths to files if possible

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the comment! But yes, I am absolutely sure the csv file is in the same directory as the .py file.

Comment: I just tried the absolute path method and it worked! Thanks a lot guys. 
But, to add more details, the .py file and the csv file are both in the same folder. Why can’t I use relative path to locate the csv file?

Comment: Hi buran, yes I did read your comment, but I'm really new to this. I finally figure out the meaning of cwd. Much thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os, csv

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

with open('gdptable1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for i in rows:
      print(i)
```

Comment: Hi john! your solution works, thanks for the help!
May I ask you why yours worked and mine didn’t?

Comment: The problem you encounter is due to the fact that you are using relative paths. Your current python working directory is not the one where your python script lies and because of this the csv file can't be found (try to run os.getcwd() to see what the working directory is without my edits). What the second line of my code does is simply changing the working directory,  setting it as the folder where this script is contained, that is also the folder where the csv file is.

Comment: Thanks John! "Your current python working directory is not the one where your python script lies" This really helped me figure out the problem!